# Using 3 to 4 columns of excel data to create batch

Tags: excel, batch-file

I'm restricted using VBA in my company network, although i can get away with batch files.
I have 3 columns of Excel data that I'd like to use in a script to create folders/sub folders.
Excel
Col 1 - just a 4 digit number, col 2 - is a 6 digit number, col 3 - is a an address
1234_123456_10 Excel St for example.
Under that folder i need to create between 4 and 5 folders that have different names, but theses names are the same in each main folder. So the only change that is variable is the example (1234_123456_10 Excel St)

1234_123456_10 Excel St

Folder 1

Folder 2

Folder 3

Folder 4

Any thoughts?

Comment: Batch files cannot read Excel data, but can read plain text csv data. Why aren't you trying to do this with VBA? Also if you are trying to do this using a batch file and CSV data, use the search engine at the top of the page, reading and using specific fields of records in a csv file has been asked, and answered multiple times before, as has creating sub-directories within one or more directories. It would be even better, if you had access to PowerShell, but for your stated data, a batch file would probably suffice.

Comment: The computers a restricted in our network, so no VBA and i've just stumbled on not batch files either as local access to the local drive is restricted, so eveything runs off \\\server-name\share. So, i'll have to look at PS. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: If they've blocked VBA (which would be crazy since it's _built in to Excel_), there's absolutely no way they'd allow Powershell since it's far more powerful.

Comment: How do they prevent you from having an Excel workbook with a VBA worksheet change function, for example?  Excel wouldn't be very useful without some VBA stuff and if they give you any you can do whatever you want.  Now, it is possible that you need Administrator access to every folder on your local computer - but even then it isn't really possible to do anything without write access to %APPDATA% or %TEMP%.  So my question is, can you make a worksheet change function in an Excel worksheet or not?  And where exactly are these folders going to be created?

Comment: Sorry, I can create a VBA file but you cannot execute it. The entire local drive is read only, the user profile lives of a network share. From a sys admin point of view it makes sense, but from a script view I can understand it. My role atm is office admin (data entry) but my background is sys engineer/admin. Was just trying to make a process faster to complete with out alerting sys administrators. All good, i have powershell working with %temp% dir, plus have nutted most of the code for it. Works nicely too.